# Windows 10 - Disable Reset My PC

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

So a member of staff just thought it would be a good idea to use the "Reset My PC" function in Windows 10 as they were having trouble uninstalling some software.

Does anyone know of a way to disable "Reset My PC"? I've looked through the Windows 10 GPOs and couldn't see anything in there.

Comment: Every time you make something idiot-proof, nature invents a smarter idiot ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Systemreset.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32` is responsible for reset process. You can't delete it but you can try blocking it via group policy. However I'm not sure if this would prevent a user from resetting their computer by starting it in troubleshooting mode.

Comment: Chances are, if the PC gets in to a state where the user even gets the opportunity to get in to recovery mode, their first action will be to call me in a panic so that's an edge case I can live with!

Answer (score 3):

Access to C:\Windows\System32\systemreset.exe is denied by default for Domain Users, Reset My PC is only shows as an option if the user has administrator rights on the local pc or the domain.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can
I have a script to delete this, but please backup your system reset first
systemreset directory: C:\Windows\system32\systemreset.exe

after backup download this script and run it as admin 
http://www.mediafire.com/file/h1lyt9njf26zip2/Del-Sysres.bat

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.